# Is this a good question for seasoned advice?

Tags: discussion

Three days ago I asked the question: [Will my results differ when using a sourdough starter vs poolish for pizza dough?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/53442/will-my-results-differ-when-using-a-sourdough-starter-vs-poolish-for-pizza-dough)

It only received a single upvote in that time, so I'm curious if this question is useful, well written, and a good fit for this site? If the answer is no, what can I do to improve it?

Answer (score 4):

The question itself is well-written, and it's a reasonable and useful if slightly esoteric thing to ask about. It seems good for the site, it seems to have attracted a good answer, and it seems to have helped you. This is the sort of question we welcome (it's upvote-worthy), and I'm sorry it hasn't gotten more upvotes.

It appears that what inspired you to ask this question is the number of votes, not any specific concerns about question quality, so I think it's also worth addressing that, especially for future readers.

In general, I don't think you should ever worry about your question because it only got one vote, no matter how new you are to a site. That just demonstrates the background problem (across StackExchange): people don't vote often enough on questions. If you get a downvote, you should at least look and see if anything's wrong, though even a single downvote isn't cause for much alarm - if you don't see anything obvious, I wouldn't even bother asking on meta. And if someone provides a critical comment, there you go. But the lack of multiple upvotes should probably just make you think "oh well".

---

For a bit more detail on how normal this kind of thing is...

Here are the number and fraction of questions by score:

```
 <0  230 0.02
  0  919 0.08
  1 1555 0.14
  2 1771 0.16
  3 1460 0.13
  4 1214 0.11
  5  923 0.08
  6  665 0.06
  7  559 0.05
  8  394 0.03
  9  234 0.02
 10  240 0.02
>10 1161 0.10
```

(That's across all questions; see [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/cooking/query/264442/question-score-histogram#graph) if you want to try to filter down more.)

Keep in mind that most of those questions have been around for a lot longer than two days, and note that still, 53% of them have at most 3 votes. I would not be at all surprised if over time your question got at least a couple more votes, and ended up right  in the middle.

For comparison, the scores (as of January 12) of other questions asked the same day as yours are: 0, 4, 3, 0, 1, 1, 0, 4. The three high scoring ones are "can you make butter in a food processor/blender?" (fun and exciting, draws attention), "how do I make things egg and gluten free?" (very popular topics nowadays), "making cake balls with a not-so-sweet frosting?" (everybody loves cake). I'm not too surprised by a much more specialized question scoring a little lower - but still, just by a couple votes!

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't get any downvotes, it's probably just that most people read the title and decided that they weren't interested enough to click through. The question is now on 3 votes for 65 views.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Understandably now with the meta post I would imagine a few more votes might trickle in. I was mostly wondering if the question was a good one for this site in general.